# Cannot read property 'series' of undefined HighCharts

Tags: angular, highcharts, angular9

Want to fetch complete data with chart type and all but I get this error Cannot read property 'series' of undefined.

here is the component.ts and service file

```
const sampleData: Overview[] = [
      {
        chart: {
          type: 'column',
        },
        title: {
          text: 'Total Predected Revenue Vs Actual Revenue',
        },
        xAxis: {
          categories: [
            '2010',
            '2011',
            '2012',
            '2013',
            '2014',
            '2015',
            '2016',
            '2017',
          ],
          crosshair: true,
        },
        yAxis: {
          min: 0,
        },
        series: [
          {
            name: 'Predected',
            data: [14, 17, 9, 10, 6, 19, 6, 8],
          },
          {
            name: 'Actual',
            data: [65, 74, 44, 66, 9, 23, 36, 51],
          },
        ],
      }
    ];
```

and this is .ts file

```
data: Overview[] = [];

private onLoaded(state: OverviewLoadedState) {
    const me = this;
    me.data = state.data;
    me.error = false;
    me.loading = false;
    console.log(me.data)
  }
```

and here is the .html

```
<div *ngIf="data">
        <highcharts-chart style="width: 100%; display: block" [Highcharts]="Highcharts" [options]="data"
            [(update)]="updateDemo" [runOutsideAngular]=true>
        </highcharts-chart>
    </div>
```

Help me to slove this error.

Comment: showing series in template somewhere?

Comment: In which file you are getting this error?

Comment: Have you considered to use the Highcharts-Angular official wrapper? Please get to know with the documentation and demo base: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Probelm is in your if condition in template, change it to :-

```
<div *ngIf="data?.length > 0">
        <highcharts-chart style="width: 100%; display: block" [Highcharts]="Highcharts" [options]="data"
            [(update)]="updateDemo" [runOutsideAngular]=true>
        </highcharts-chart>
    </div>
```

because your condition would have also satisfied in case of blank array.